# BackBlaze S3 Api compatibility issues: Unable to create new bucket due to AmazonServiceException: not entitled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backblaze

With Java sdk i want to integrate my application with BackBlaze B2 cloud storage bucket but service replied with not entitled. What is the meaning of this?
*Unable to create new bucket due to AmazonServiceException: not entitled (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null)*

Comment: It's most likely an issue with either the application key or the endpoint. Can you post some of your code?